# Projection issue when matching layer projected with SRC4326 with other layer on SRC3857

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, geojson, bing-maps

When I'm trying to visualize a multipolygon layer projected on `SRC4326`, on a base layer from Bing Maps (also tested with Google Maps), *my polygons doesn't show up* on the ocidental part of the map, *as well on the antimeridian region*, as shown in this image:

[image]

The project is set for a dynamic reprojection on SRC3857. Any hints on solving these two problems? This layer was originally a GeoJSON polygon collection, but now ingested on PostGIS.

Comment: Check the extent as it may be 0-360 longitudes, rather than +/-180 range.

Comment: ... and multipolygons touching the North Pole, South pole or antimeridian (180°E/W) may break the rendering.

Comment: Using the openlayers plugin? If so, delete it asap and install quickmapservices instead.